# Create Resource Manager VM with Window Updates disabled

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-resource-manager

I can create VM using the following instructions [Create a new VM](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-windows-capture-image/)

The problem I'm encountering is creating this VM with windows updates disabled. I have tried editing the following line (-EnableAutoUpdate)

```
$vm=Set-AzureRmVMOperatingSystem -VM $vm -Windows -ComputerName $vmName -Credential $cred -ProvisionVMAgent -EnableAutoUpdate
```

but still when I start the VM up window updates is enabled, I've tried -EnableAutoUpdate false but its still enabled.

**Update**

I came across the following when debugging the PowerShell in Visual Studio if I do the following:

```
Set-AzureRmVMOperatingSystem -VM $vmConfig -Windows -ComputerName $computerName -Credential $cred -ProvisionVMAgent:$false -EnableAutoUpdate:$false
```

When I go to view the object OSProfile > WindowsConfiguration no properties have been set, here is the OSProfileText:

```
{
"computerName": "machine1",
"adminUsername": "admin",
"adminPassword": "tp{.}D>nMzH~Y2_",
"customData": null,
"windowsConfiguration": {
"provisionVMAgent": null,
"enableAutomaticUpdates": null,
"timeZone": null,
"additionalUnattendContent": null,
"winRM": null
},
"linuxConfiguration": null,
"secrets": null
}
```

If I do :

```
Set-AzureRmVMOperatingSystem -VM $vmConfig -Windows -ComputerName $computerName -Credential $cred -ProvisionVMAgent:$true -EnableAutoUpdate:$true
```

properties are added and this is the OSProfileText property

```
{
"computerName": "machine1",
"adminUsername": "admin",
"adminPassword": "tp{.}D>nMzH~Y2_",
"customData": "RmFsc2U=",
"windowsConfiguration": {
"provisionVMAgent": true,
"enableAutomaticUpdates": true,
"timeZone": null,
"additionalUnattendContent": null,
"winRM": null
},
"linuxConfiguration": null,
"secrets": null
}
```

This works with out any problems using Microsoft.Azure.Management.Compute SDK and setting the following

```
WindowsConfiguration = new WindowsConfiguration {     
                ProvisionVMAgent = true, 
                EnableAutomaticUpdates = false,   
            }
```

Comment: Does the VM join to a domain? Windows update option can be overwrite by GPO.

Comment: It's not in a domain. I can create the VM with window updates disabled through the rest Api. The powershell equivalent does not woe it I'm missing something

Comment: hmm, any luck with a boolean? `$false` instead of string `false`

Answer (score 0):

Try with `-EnableAutoUpdate $false`. This should resolve it.

In Powershell there is no boolean `false` or `true` but this is `$false` and `$true`.

Comment: I've tried the following and still the same: -EnableAutoUpdate $false and -EnableAutoUpdate:$false